# how to fix "Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled" error while running java

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, java-7

i am using eclipse to develop a web application and i have encountered a problem when i am trying to run my application on server from within eclipse.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f41e4e610b0, pid=3463, tid=139924549404416
#
# JRE version: 7.0_09-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.5-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0+0x11670b0]  void WTF::freeOwnedGPtr<_GdkEvent>(_GdkEvent*)+0x15e00
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

i googled it and found a possible solution [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/dont-use-java-7-are-you) that suggests : "A minimal workaround is to add -XX:LoopUnrollLimit=1 as an argument." the problem is i don't know where to add this argument and how to add it. can any one help me about it?

thanks.

EDIT : I updated my jdk from 1.7_9 to 1.7_40 but problem stands still.

Comment: Does your application crash or eclipse?

Comment: I guess you are facing one of these issues: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393201 or https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392967

Comment: @katona i guess eclipse crashes

Comment: and i am using eclipse indigo, but i read that it is a jre bug

Comment: Have you tried to update the JRE? You are using a very old version.

Comment: i am trying to do that. but it is kind of hard in ubuntu :D

Comment: @TwoThe i updated to 7u40 . no luck

Comment: Do you managed to find a solution? I'm having the same problem, tried everything but so far no luck, it keeps crashing unexpectadly whenever it wants.

Comment: @DamienPirsy i updated to eclipse kepler

Comment: @DamienPirsy this problem finally drove me to intellij's arm

Answer (score 11):

In linux mint 16, for me, the solution was change the eclipse theme from GTK to Classic and write in eclipse.ini this:

`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

Comment: My Eclipse begins to die after dist-upgrade, to 14.04 from 13.10... After reinstall OpenJDk, Oracle Jdk and others, your solution seems to work for me, thanks

Comment: Nice. I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and suddenly pentaho kettle stopped working. Adding this to the spoon.sh fixes the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse Kepler. Changing the browser (window> web browser> system default) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

i don't know if this solution applies to every one or not, but i managed to solve this by updating my eclipse from indigo to kepler.

Answer (score 2):

This error log looks as mine that I received when I've tried to open the Eclipse Marketplace. The Eclipse simply closed after that. My OS is the Linux Mint Derbian and I'm working with Eclipse Luna 4.4.1.
I found this tip on the Derbian's forum and it worked for me.
[Re: Eclipse Luna Crashed on XFCE](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=115477#p545781)

I add the line to eclipse/eclipse.in:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: thanks. thread is old and i am now using intellij :) hope your answer helps some other googler

Answer (score 1):

The Erick Alves Answer works for me. I add the code

--launcher.GTK_version
2

then, below  my eclipse.ini works.

```
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
--launcher.GTK_version
2
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```