# Java Fatal Run time error

Tags: java, debugging

Hi All I get the error below when I run a java program in a linux terminal. I have not seen this before and do not know how to start debugging it. Does anyone have any suggestion. 
Does anyone know if it is a problem with the installation or the program?
Thank you

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f604e1c3bad, pid=2320, tid=140053630809856
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b32) (build 1.7.0_65-b32)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.3
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libX11.so.6+0x85bad]  XkbSetDetectableAutoRepeat+0xd
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /srv/harvester/dist/hs_err_pid2320.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Comment: possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332489/how-to-fix-failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled-error-whil

Comment: @Beezy Doesn't look like enough of a duplicate of that one to close.

Comment: Can you post the contents of /srv/harvester/dist/hs_err_pid2320.log?

Comment: is it possible to add an attachment