# Unable to understand debug report

Tags: java, tomcat

While running my server in debug mode , I get the error log posted below. Please help me to understand this report

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x69345c00, pid=6004, tid=4664
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_40-b43) (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.0-b56 mixed mode windows-x86 )
Problematic frame:
V [jvm.dll+0x35c00]
Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\Users\ANUKUL\AppData\Local\Temp\\hs_err_pid6004.log
If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332489/how-to-fix-failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled-error-whil)

Comment: what it says: C:\Users\ANUKUL\AppData\Local\Temp\\hs_err_pid6004.log

Comment: Its a file that that contain some stuff let me know if you want this file to know the issue..

Answer (score 2):

You crashed the JVM. Nice job! (These are fairly rare.)

If you were using 100% Java code (no JNI), then *this isn't your fault*. Upgrade to the latest patch-level of your JVM and see if the problem is solved. Otherwise, file a bug report with Oracle.

If you *were* using JNI, then you or the library/libraries you are using probably handed bad data to the JVM and caused it to crash. Update and/or fix those libraries and try again.

The other error (`Failed to write core dump`) is probably due to a file-permissions error.