# SIGSEGV signal while executing "Eclipse Application" run configuration for my Xtext project

Tags: eclipse, xtext, segmentation-fault, macos-mojave

Since my computer has been updated to Mojave (macOS), I get the following error when I am trying to execute an Xtext project (Run As -> Eclipse Application):

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff51115248, pid=10464, tid=775
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.1+13) (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
>   Problematic frame:
>   C  [CoreFoundation+0x8248]  CFDictionaryGetValue+0xb
>
> No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/hs_err_pid10464.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>     http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>   See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Unfortunately, I do not have so much information to share.

**Here my setup:**

- Mojave, v. 10.14.1
- Eclipse DSL Tools, v: 2018-09 (4.9.0), Build id: 20180917-1800
- java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS, Oracle one

**What I have tested:**

- Running the `ulimit -c unimited command`
- Reinstalling Eclipse
- Reinstalling my JDK. I also tested on OpenJDK.
- Running on a fresh computer. I don't have the bug on macOs Sierra.
- I tested the solution mention here:

  - [how to fix “Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled” error while running java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332489/how-to-fix-failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled-error-whil)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538377

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Christian Dietrich: many thanks for the link!

Here the current workaround explained in the link: to add the '-nosplash' in Arguments tab of run configuration.